# Function to check for criteria

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, while-loop

### Edit: It was a typo in my function that caused my problem. I typed $sytem instead of $syStem.

---

I'm trying to make this code into a function.

I'm checking the last status records of a customer. If each record has a 0 in `Delay` then it is a success. If one or more records isn't a 0 then it's a fail.

But I'm getting success for every customer while they have different numbers than 0 in `Delay`. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
    //Shows if one or more replications have a delay
    function delay_total($conn, $customer, $sytem){
        $sql_customer       = "SELECT Cust_ID, Cust_Name, Env_Lines FROM `Customer` WHERE Cust_Name = '$customer' LIMIT 0,1";
        //echo $sql_customer;
        $customer_selection = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_customer);
        $customer_row       = mysqli_fetch_assoc($customer_selection);
        $env_lines          = $customer_row["Env_Lines"];
        $cust_id            = $customer_row["Cust_ID"];
        //echo $cust_id;
        $sql_last_records   = "SELECT Delay FROM $system WHERE Cust_ID = $cust_id ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT $env_lines";
        //echo $sql_last_records;
        $record_selection   = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_last_records);               

        $count = 0;
        while($source_row = mysqli_fetch_array($record_selection)){
          if ($source_row['Delay'] == 0 ) {
              $count++;
          }
        }
        if($count != mysqli_num_rows($record_selection)) {
          echo "Fail";
        } else echo "Success";
    }

    ?>
```

gist.github.com/R2D2-05/da1cc473a68dccc3be35

Comment: what's the values of your "Env_Lines"? If it's too small, you may not get any records to check.

Comment: those are the last number of records the function should check for. So its always 1 or more.

Comment: @R2D2 are you sure that $record_selection returns a row?

Comment: thank you for making me check that, I found out that I made a type in my function. @bassxzero

Answer (score 1):

I think that if your query returned zero records then you will also get success (because `$count` is equal to **0** which is also equal to **0** records.

You can fix this scenario by verifying that at least one record was found, change:

```
if($count != mysqli_num_rows($record_selection)) {
```

To

```
if($count != mysqli_num_rows($record_selection) || mysqli_num_rows($record_selection) == 0) {
```

Comment: That wasn't the problem but it did help me to get the right criteria, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What is $system? is it your table or something? or you have **Delay table**

better you use join or inner join to get that. it's like this

```
SELECT Customer.Cust_ID, Customer.Cust_Name, Customer.Env_Lines,
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Delay
ON Customer.Cust_ID=$system.Cust_ID
WHERE Customer.Cust_Name = '$customer';
```

Comment: Yes $system is a table but I found out it was just a silly typo in my function.